# Unable to ping my wireless laptops

Tags: networking, ping

Im new and currently learning networking so bear with me.
I been pulling my hair for weeks trying to ping my laptops.

I got a netcomm wireless router where it has two desktop computer connected to it via Ethernet and they communicate fine with each other.

The problems occur when I try to ping my wireless laptop(on the same network but wireless) from my wired desktop(also on the same network). I get no reply from my laptop(100% packet loss) and I get "host unreachable" if I ping my desktop from laptop. I tried turning off firewall and then trying again but got the same result.

It somehow works with my Android phone(on the same network) as it can wirelessly ping my desktop computer. After this discovery I thought the problem resided in my wireless adapter and tried to ping my desktop with my other laptop but still the same result.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Info:
Netcomm Wireless NF4V

Desktop computer has linux installed.
Laptop computers have win7 installed.

Ping to laptop from desktop:
Problem - no reply

Ping to desktop from laptop:
Problem - host unreachable

Ping to desktop from android phone:
No problems

Ping to desktop from desktop :
No problem

Ping to laptop from laptop:
No problem

All laptops, devices and desktop are connected to "netcomm wireless nf4v"  and are on the same network.

**Edit :** My wireless router has nothing enabled in Guest/Virtual Access Points under wireless and Clients Isolation checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Does everything else work? Is `ping` the only problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No its the connection, I can't ssh as well from desktop to laptop

Comment: Then you've done a very poor job of describing the problem. Do they get IP addresses? Can they ping the wireless router?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The wireless router can ping all its hosts, no problem

Comment: @Rickx Did you ever figure this out? I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Log into the router.

Under "Wireless - Guest/Virtual Access Points" make sure nothing is enabled. In the very unlikely event that anything is enabled, update your question with the details and I'll update my answer.

Otherwise, under "Wireless - Basic" look for the "Clients Isolation" checkbox. Uncheck it. Press the "Apply/Save" button.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try upgrading the router's firmware, resetting it to factory defaults and reconfiguring it, or (worst case) replacing the router.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall settings can be the reason. Please find try disabling fire wall in windows 7. More details can be found here. http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7

Comment: Already tried it with disabling the firewall. Still the same result