# Why do I get timeout when I try to ping my laptop from my desktop? (both are on the same wifi home network)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a TP-Link  Wifi Router.  300M Wireless N Router Model No. TL-WR841N

On my laptop (Windows 10 Home) I did a ipconfig and got the

Wireless LAN Adapter ipV4 address of 192.168.0.107

Ethernet Adapter (WSL) ipV4 address of 172.18.192.1

**But when I ping the laptop from the desktop, I get a timeout**

```
Pinging 192.168.0.107 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.107:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
PS C:\Users\Me> ping 172.18.192.1

Pinging 172.18.192.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 172.18.192.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I also looked at this [SO](https://superuser.com/questions/878543/unable-to-ping-my-wireless-laptops) but it did not fix it.

**But when I ping the desktop from the laptop, I get a reply.**

Comment: when you ping from where?

Comment: @Zina great question! I tried both directions now and find one direction works. So I need to find out why the other direction fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ethernet and Wireless are on two different subnets on one router per your post printout in your question.

Go into the Router Setup and disable (turn off) Wireless Isolation.

Some routers have a default setup to isolate Wireless devices from Ethernet devices. This is not helpful for wireless laptops however.

You may need to restart your router, or it may be best to make a note of settings, reset it, and set it up again to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not see an option in the TP-Link Router for "Wireless Isolation". I do see `AP Isolation` and the box is unchecked.

Comment: Your post shows two subnets from one router. Isolation is how that happens. Look in the wireless profile setup for wireless isolation. Try restarting the router.  You may need to reset it and set it up again.

Comment: I tried both directions now and find one direction works. So I need to find out why the other direction fails. (updated my question)

Comment: Is it still isolated if one direction works?

Comment: Could be but really one router should only have one subnet so something is wrong in the router

Comment: not sure if this is relevant but my printer is connected via ethernet cable to the router.

Comment: You really should have all devices on the same subnet and I really do not understand why your router is producing two subnets if isolation is off (assuming off means no isolation).

Comment: I don't know, I am not a network guy. I installed the router straight out of the box.  No customsettings.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer support line about 2 subnets and how to have 1. Normally the isolation setting fixes this.

Comment: No, if packets can flow in one direction, then I don't think having a different subnet is the issue - but again, I don't know for sure.

Comment: The packet flow you see depends on the routing inside the router and you would have to set up routing in the other direction. I think the one direction routing may be because of the isolation setup. I have not seen this so I am not certain. Normally, with multiple routers and subnets you cannot just ping across without putting in special routing.

Comment: Is it possible that the Windows 10 firewall on the laptop is blocking the ping from the desktop?